# How to compare fingerprint image using NBIS software

Tags: fingerprint

I have taken fingerprint image from my device and I want to compare two finger at server side using NBIS tools.

I have ANSI,ISO and JPEG file of every finger.

I tried to verify it using mindtct and bozorth3.

But mindtct take ANSI/NIST and WSQ file in input to generate xyt file. So How can I convert my JPEG and ISO file to WSQ file?

When I have tried with raw data than it is converted in WSQ using CWSQ but I have problem with JPEG file.

Comment: Could you share any error log or code that you have tried to help others to understand the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

`bozorth_to_gallery` take `xyt_struct` in parameter.

You could have a look to this for instance : https://github.com/freedesktop/libfprint/blob/bcfe0ad12ce87a95bd836f1b88815d9928b6a382/libfprint/fpi-img.c

Comment: @ankitpatel Is it useful ?